# Convert date column to new UTC date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, utc

I wrote the following query on a SQL Server DB to **convert a datetime column to a UTC date column.**

```
select datetime
       , dateadd(minute,-datepart(tz,datetime),datetime) datetime_dt_utc
from table1
```

But I get the same same datetime for both columns.

What do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. And dateadd and datepart are both product specific. )

Comment: thanks for the info. Just added it to the question. 

Its a SQL db

Comment: Hi @Hankiee20 SQL is just a language not a database. Database can be: Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer and so on...

Comment: You probably mean MS SQL Server. (Many products implement SQL, it's a languade specified by ISO/ANSI.)

Comment: Yes, MS SQL server

Comment: SQL Server version and datatype of `datetime` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), datetime)
```

- The `GETDATE()` will return the current time
- The `GETUTCDATE()` will retunr the current UTC time
- The `DATEDIFF` function  will calculate the difference between this two datetimes in hours
- The `DATEADD` function  will add this hours to your current datetime.

Another way is via usign the AT TIME ZONE

```
SELECT datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' from table1
```

You can check your time zone with:

```
select CURRENT_TIMEZONE ( )
```

And use this:

```
SELECT datetime  AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
from table1
```

If you are in 'Pacific Standard Time' timezone

Comment: If i select with getdate() i will get the current date right?. I would like to get the date that is defined in the datetime column

Comment: Hello @Henkiee20 , your column name is datetime ? I have it in my query...

Comment: Hello @Henkiee20 I have added the explanation in my answer...

Comment: This approach is wrong... it does not consider daylight saving time. If the server is +08:00 at the time query was executed but the datetime refers to a date when server was +07:00 then the UTC time will be off by one hour.

Comment: @Henkiee20 no it doesn't. Salman already mentioned the problem. You can't assume the *current* offset is the one used by the stored value

Comment: The code that uses `AT TIME ZONE` doesn't suffer from that problem though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have reacted when I have seen Salman's comment... There is also a SWITCHOFFSET approach but I am not sure how it is done so I wil test it little bit and then add that also here... :)

Comment: @VBoka yes. Also note that OP did not mention datatype being used. If it is `datetimeoffset` then you just need `SELECT datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`